# preg_replace regex for removing product sizes from string

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove a size from titles i.e.

```
Shift Fuel Street Motorcycle Riding Shoes Size 10
```

to become

```
Shift Fuel Street Motorcycle Riding Shoes
```

so far I have regex to remove grams, centimeters etc. but those are a bit different as digit there are before string, so the pattern for those is:

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\S)(\b|\(|\[)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*cm($|\s|\.|;|,|\)|\])/is', '${1}${2}', $string);
```

Can you help with modifying pattern above so can work with sizes as in example at the top of this post/question?

many thanks

Comment: I am sure there is a better regex to solve the entire problem. Working on the regex provided would be a pain for us helpers. Please describe your problem in a larger extent including this "cm" or "grams".

Comment: ok so please ignore the cm and grams but provide the regex for sizing only

Comment: `preg_replace("/\s+Size\s+\d+/", '', $text);`

Comment: great stuff, perfected a bit: /\s+size\s+(\d+|m|l|xl|xxl)/is

Comment: please add it as a response so can close the anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the size:

```
preg_replace("/\s+Size\s+\d+/", '', $text);
```

UPDATE to support "Size: 10":

```
preg_replace("/\s+Size:?\s+\d+/", '', $text);
```

Comment: just quick one, any ideas how to add possibility of such a delimeter like `Size:` as sometimes it can be Size: 10